# Asset pipeline is broken: Not compiling on the fly css and js files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I started a new Rails 3.2.5 projects and the asset pipeline is not working anymore. CSS and Javascript file are not compiling anymore.

This is the output from the logs when try to generate the asset:

```
    Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-16 23:59:11 -0700
Served asset /application.css - 200 OK (0ms)
[2012-06-16 23:59:11] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:

Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-16 23:59:11 -0700
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (0ms)
[2012-06-16 23:59:11] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /Users/greg/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
183:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Update**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shorai</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body id=<%= params[:controller].sub('_controller', '') %>>

  <% if current_user %>
    <%= current_user.name %>
    <%= link_to "Log out", signout_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in", "/auth/37signals" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
  
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update2:**

## application.scss

```
 *
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**update3:**
http://f.imgtmp.com/Onpqv.png

I don't know what is causing this, anyone has an idea?
Greg

Comment: upgrade to rails 3.2.6, because 3.2.5 is broken in many ways...

Comment: I still have the issue even with rails 3.2.6 :(

Comment: The output looks like what you might see when visiting a page in the browser. Are you running in dev, or production? What happens when you run rake assets:precompile?

Comment: I am in dev and when i run rake assets:precompile, the files are properly compiled.

Comment: Are you using .css.erb and/or .js.erb files?

Comment: Would you mind posting your application.html.erb and the view that it is trying to render when you visit the page that generates these errors in the logs? What does your browser show when you visit a page?

Comment: The pages are rendering properly but I doesn't load all the css and js files. It loads for ever. And when I try to look at the source code of application.css http://localhost:3000/asssets/applications.css i get the error I posted previously.

Comment: Can I have a look at the application.css file?

Comment: Isn't it this `ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` that is the issue? It looks like to me application.css and application.js are being served correctly.

Comment: No they don't: http://f.imgtmp.com/Onpqv.png

Answer (score 7):

I got this error when I had caching enabled (in development mode) with *memcached* storage, but the *memcached* process was not running (Rails 3.2.8, Win7).

The solution therefore was to simply start *memcached* and reboot the Rails server.

Comment: Or if you aren't using memcache storage, be sure to comment out the `config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store` line in your `development.rb` file.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after activating memcache as cache store (`config.cache_store = :dalli_store`).  I could solve it by deactivating Rack::Cache middleware explicitly (`config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = nil`), or by setting

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8366.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by disabling cache in dev environment. 
I think cache doesn't play well with asset on-the-fly compilation

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with -v 3.2.5.

After hours of debugging, I put in a workaround. It's not great but it gets me moving until I can solve it, or someone else has better luck!

I'm curious if this workaround works for you too, Gregory...

In config/application.rb I had to explicitly add the load paths for my assets... so:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "stylesheets")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "assets", "javascripts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("lib", "assets", "javascripts")
```

If you have assets in engines, they also need to be explicitly added. It worked OK in -v 3.1.x. The fact that this workaround fixes the issue seems to point to either a bug (surely others would've found it by now) or else some configuration change in 3.2.5.